# Formatting numbers with thousands separator Smarty PHP

Tags: smarty

Im trying to format numbers with thousands separator Smarty.

So for example 1000 becomes 1,000.

Thanks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

or you can use php function inside smarty, this is for number_format, you can use other php function too :)

```
PHP : number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');

SMARTY :
{$number|number_format:2:".":","}
```

Answer (score 5):

or just in smarty use `{$var|number_format:0}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [string_format](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifier.string.format.php), it uses [sprintf](http://www.php.net/sprintf) to format your string.

Comment: I think sprintf cannot do thousand separators