# How do I format a variable with commas after every 3 numbers?

Tags: php, variables, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to reformat a number with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508240/how-to-reformat-a-number-with-commas)
>   [Formatting numbers with thousands separator Smarty PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193710/formatting-numbers-with-thousands-separator-smarty-php)
>   [Format a number with grouped thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424120/format-a-number-with-grouped-thousands)

For example the following code:-

```
{php}echo $youtube->_views;{/php}
```

returns 2556789 and I want it formatted like this; 2,556,789

Comment: [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) an obviously named function :-)

Comment: you've asked this aview hours ago!

Comment: Wasn't your previous question already closed? Please don't duplicate your questions if they are closed for good reason.

Comment: Make sure you don't make the same mistake as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111969/issue-with-number-format-multiply-numbers-with-comma-formatted)

Answer (score 2):

[This topic](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8986) says how to do it:

```
{$myvar|number_format:2:".":","}
```