# Issue with number_format() multiply numbers with comma (formatted)

Tags: php

I am having a problem with number_format. Here is how I am trying to use it:

When I try to multiply it with quantity it returns 1. for example

```
1,200.00 * 2
```

It returns 1. How can I make it return 2,400.00?

What I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot multiply formatted numbers. You should do all of your calculations *before* you format the final result.

Comment: Can't I remove the formatting? I already did the calculations :(

Comment: No, you're trying to multiply _after_ you have formatted the number; multiplication is a calculation too, you should do it before you format the number. You _could_ remove the formatting, but that would be inefficient.

Comment: So i have to change all session stored prices, db prices to numbers without format, use only format when showing them on screen.. that what you wanna say?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm saying. You should keep prices in `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` columns in your database, and only format them when you actually _need_ to display them formatted.

Comment: @AhmedFouad Hey, you wrote the code. He's trying to help you.

Comment: @AhmedFouad You *can* [unformat money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money/5140046#5140046) but lanzz is actually right here. You should do all calculation *before* you display the formatted string.